# docker container fail to connect to docker daemon if use /usr/sbin/init to start the container

Tags: docker, centos7, daemon

```
sudo docker run -it --name="cms_docker_without_init_with_port" --privileged=true --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/cms/iris4_build:/home/cms/iris4_build -v /home/cms/jenkins:/home/cms/jenkins -v /home/cms/bin:/home/cms/bin -v /home/cms/cmn:/home/cms/cmn -v /home/cms/wls/bin:/home/cms/wls/bin -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -v /etc/group:/etc/group -p 22000:22 artifact.oocl.com/fwk/cms_docker:1
```

I use above command to start the docker container, the cms_docker CAN connect to docker daemon in target VM. 
There is contos7 inside the container, and I want to start the sshd service. I found in the docker official document, have to add `/usr/sbin/init` when start the container.

https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/centos#dockerfile-for-systemd-base-image

So I add the `"/usr/sbin/init"` when start the container. The command is below:

```
sudo docker run -it --name="cms_docker_without_init_with_port" --privileged=true --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/cms/iris4_build:/home/cms/iris4_build -v /home/cms/jenkins:/home/cms/jenkins -v /home/cms/bin:/home/cms/bin -v /home/cms/cmn:/home/cms/cmn -v /home/cms/wls/bin:/home/cms/wls/bin -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -v /etc/group:/etc/group -p 22000:22 artifact.oocl.com/fwk/cms_docker:1 /usr/sbin/init
```

But after I added `/usr/sbin/init` to start container, the cms_docker cannot connect to the docker daemon.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmPWs.png)

I need to start the sshd service and also need cms_docker connect to docker daemon. But now it seems there is conflict. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: This might be easier to run without Docker, especially since you're disabling so many of its isolation features.  Why do you need an ssh daemon?  (If you were running it directly on the host, would you need to ssh into the _process_?)  Can you add your Dockerfile to the question?  If you do run an init system instead of your process, what makes the init system launch the server?

Comment: Hi David, I post the docker file at the end.

Comment: Hi David, I post the docker file at the end. 
The docker container is used to serve as jenkins slave node. The jenkins master node will ssh to the docker container and use it as a slave node.
The key point is that the -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock not work after I add /usr/usbin/init in the docker run command.